# Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required en CodeIgniter 2

Tags: php, codeigniter

Cloné una plataforma alojada en Gitlab e intento trabajar en local (xammp - Windows). Está construida con CodeIgniter 2. Qué me falta configurar según el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por cierto ese archivo de autoload está en esa ubicación sin errores.

Answer (score 0):

Seguramente el archivo que intenta cargar contiene información "privada" por lo que el dueño del repositorio añadió ese archivo al .gitignore para evitar que se filtre dicha información. Seguro que el dueño del repositorio puede ayudarte, incluso igual tienes información al respecto en el readme o en la wiki.

Comment: Gracias @Jorge Montejo.